# sci-fi book earlier than 1987 dealing with space flight and a short curved sword

Tags: story-identification

Started reading this book on a military transport plane from Germany to Fort Hood, I got halfway through but left on plane while being rushed off. Has space travel but the main group of people use short curved swords which they are trained on from childhood.If I remember correctly the cover has a man dressed like the character on assassin's creed kneeling down on the edge of a cliff looking down on a barren world. Sorry I don'the have much more information.

Comment: @otis In future, please mark the "poorer" question as duplicate, since this has a better answer, even though it is newer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a lot to go on here, but is it perhaps [The Faded Sun trilogy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faded_Sun_Trilogy) by C. J. Cherryh?

[Amazon plot summary](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0886778697):

> They were the mri-tall, secretive, bound by honor and the rigid dictates of their society. For aeons this golden-skinned, golden-eyed race had provided the universe mercenary soldiers of almost unimaginable ability. But now the mri have faced an enemy unlike any other-an enemy whose only way of war is widespread destruction. These "humans" are mass fighters, creatures of the herb, and the mri have been slaughtered like animals. Now, in the aftermath of war, the mri face extinction. It will be up to three individuals to save whatever remains of this devastated race: a warrior--one of the last survivors of his kind; a priestess of this honorable people; and a lone human--a man sworn to aid the enemy of his own kind. Can they retrace the galaxy-wide path of this nomadic race back through millennia to reclaim the ancient world that first gave them life?